# Why can't "input data" get decoded in a normal, readable format in an explorer, in some cases?

Tags: transactions, uniswap, explorers, decoding

Let's say, this transaction https://testnet.snowtrace.io/tx/0x86895afcc3768254e5a1257790e95cdcd7402df6c88ed098c012a809a9be3e1d

The function `router.swapExactAVAXForTokens` was called here. However, in the "input data" it's all in the 16x based digit format.

When I change the address of a contract in the code which will cause an error and a trasction will revert, the input data would be shown in the normal text format, format:

https://testnet.snowtrace.io/tx/0x60d11697a0bcb83a87154a21ff680dff800082666982b46b76f920a3f7f1e088

Why? What does depend on? The code is the same in both cases, that is.

Previously when I had errors

Answer (score 1):

I can only assume that is because the first transaction is directed towards an externally owned address [0x60ae616a2155ee3d9a68541ba4544862310933d4](https://testnet.snowtrace.io/address/0x60ae616a2155ee3d9a68541ba4544862310933d4) and not a contract. Because there's no contract ABI, it doesn't assume that the input data is to be decoded in some meaningful way (other than perhaps utf8 text).

The second transaction is aimed at [0xD8D37bA976D29D55c70Bc4f025Da14BD3013CDda](https://testnet.snowtrace.io/address/0xd8d37ba976d29d55c70bc4f025da14bd3013cdda), a contract. And even though no ABI might be submitted, it could deduce this from other common ABIs. I'm guessing that it is "smart" and takes over the ABI from the Uniswap contract.

Edit to clarify:

- first transaction
  [image]

has the recipient [0x60ae616a2155ee3d9a68541ba4544862310933d4](https://testnet.snowtrace.io/address/0x60ae616a2155ee3d9a68541ba4544862310933d4)
[image]

- second transaction
  [image]

has the recipient [0xD8D37bA976D29D55c70Bc4f025Da14BD3013CDda](https://testnet.snowtrace.io/address/0xd8d37ba976d29d55c70bc4f025da14bd3013cdda)

[image]

An "externally owned account" means that someone holds the private keys to that account and it's not a contract.

As Ismael correctly pointed out in the comments, [0x60ae616a2155ee3d9a68541ba4544862310933d4](https://snowtrace.io/address/0x60ae616a2155ee3d9a68541ba4544862310933d4) on Avalanche mainnet is a valid contract instance of trader joe's, not on testnet however.

Comment: what's `externally owned address`?

Comment: No, they (transactions) both have been sent identically, and the only difference is the addresses used in a script. However, those addresses are of the same contract deployed twise, namely -- 2 copies of the same address.

Comment: @Rurik21Ami The address `0x60ae..` is Trader Joe contract on avalanche mainnet, but it isn't a contract on avalanche testnet.

Comment: `As Ismael correctly pointed out in the comments,` --> Ismaeil hasn't pointed out that correctly because 0x60ae616a2155ee3d9a68541ba4544862310933d4 exists on Fuji as well --> https://testnet.snowtrace.io/address/0x60ae616a2155ee3d9a68541ba4544862310933d4